# How to make column scrollable only after widgets resizing when the keyboard pops up flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a log in screen wrap in a Column like this
[My log in screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiX1v.png) [Log in screen when keyboard pop up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKIV5.png)
I want the column scrollable only after widgets resizing when the keyboard pops up

I have tried wrap Column inside a SingleChildScrollView but it make it widgets doesnt resizing
[log in screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqEKR.png)

I want to make it look like this when the keyboard pop up
[log in screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7C6jK.png)
When scoll down it look like this
[log in screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QU9mN.png)

```
return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Flexible(flex: 2,child: Container(),),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  SvgPicture.asset(
                    "assets/images/ic_instagram.svg",
                    colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(isDarkMode ? primaryColor : Colors.black, BlendMode.srcIn) ,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20.0,),
                  InputTextField(
                    fillColor: isDarkMode ? Colors.grey.shade800 : Colors.grey[100],
                    borderSideColor:isDarkMode ? Colors.black : Colors.grey.shade400,
                    hintText: "Phone number, email or username",
                    textInputType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    textEditingController: _emailController,
                    isPassword: false,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 15.0,),
                  InputTextField(
                    fillColor: isDarkMode ? Colors.grey.shade800 : Colors.grey[100],
                    borderSideColor:isDarkMode ? Colors.black : Colors.grey.shade400,
                    hintText: "Password",
                    textInputType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
                    textEditingController: _passwordController,
                    isPassword: true,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 17.0,),
                  CustomButton(
                    buttonContext: const Text(
                      "Log in",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {

                    },
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 9.0,),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          print("a");
                        },
                        child: const Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),
                          child: Text(
                            "Forgot your login details? ",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.grey,
                                fontSize: 12.0,
                                letterSpacing: 0.1
                            ),

                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          print("a");
                        },
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),
                          child: Text(
                            "Get help logging in.",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                                color: isDarkMode ? Colors.white : Colors.purple.shade900,
                                fontSize: 12.0,
                                letterSpacing: 0.1,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],

                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 5.0,),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: Divider(
                          color: Colors.grey[400],
                          height: 36,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                        child: Text(
                          "OR",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.grey.shade600,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Divider(
                          color: Colors.grey[400],
                          height: 36,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 5.0,),
                  CustomButton(
                    buttonContext: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        SvgPicture.asset(
                          "assets/images/ic_facebook.svg",
                          colorFilter: const ColorFilter.mode(primaryColor, BlendMode.srcIn) ,
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(width: 8.0), // Adjust the spacing between icon and text
                        const Text(
                          'Logging in with Facebook',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {

                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),


            Flexible(flex: 1,child: Container(),),
            Divider(
              color: Colors.grey[400],
              height: 36,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    print("a");
                  },
                  child: const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),
                    child: Text(
                      "Forgot your login details? ",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          fontSize: 12.0,
                          letterSpacing: 0.1
                      ),

                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    print("a");
                  },
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),
                    child: Text(
                      "Get help logging in.",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                          color: isDarkMode ? Colors.white : Colors.purple.shade900,
                          fontSize: 12.0,
                          letterSpacing: 0.1,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],

            ),

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your Column() in a SingleChildScrollView()

Comment: I have tried that but it make the widgets doesnt resizing when keyboard pop up

Comment: oh, there is a bool property on scaffold `resizeToAvoidBottomInset`. set that to true

Comment: if i wrap my Column() in SingleChildScrollView() it wont resizing when keyboard pop up even if `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` set to true and i want it both resizing and scrollable